# MDX query picking columns on different condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, mdx

As shown in the below query,

```
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] } ON COLUMNS
 ,{([Product].[City].[City].ALLMEMBERS)} ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works]
Where ([Promotions].[City].&[Seattle],[Geography].[State-Province].&[WA]&[US])
```

This will list all the Product City names in row-wise and the column sales amount. Now I have to fetch the same column based on different City and State-Provine Name. So for that, I can repeat the query like this

```
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] } ON COLUMNS
 ,{([Product].[City].[City].ALLMEMBERS)} ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works]
Where ([Promotions].[City].&[LA],[Geography].[State-Province].&[CA]&[US])
```

Now I have these two queries returning same Product City names, but Two sales amount columns based on different conditions. I want to join these results like below

```
SELECT 
  {
   [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] EXISTS ([Promotions].[City].&[Seattle],
                                              [Geography].[State-Province].&[WA]&[US]),
   [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] EXISTS ([Promotions].[City].&[LA],
                                              [Geography].[State-Province].&[CA]&[US])

  } ON COLUMNS
 ,{([Product].[City].[City].ALLMEMBERS)} ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Now, this query should produce a single result with Product City names as rows and Col1 and Col2 of Internet Sales amount based on different conditions. But the problem is, the last query is giving me an error

> "Parser: The syntax for 'Exists' is incorrect."

I am new to MDX, could someone please help me on how to join these results?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem based on the solution described here!

[to-join-2-mdx-queries-with-same-hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49173030/to-join-2-mdx-queries-with-same-hierarchy)